# Vue templates debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js

Maybe its just the fact that I'm not used to using them, but it's hard for me to read and debug templates. I’m trying to figure out if there is a way to use JSX outside of render method or a good linter that would look inside the templates, but can't seem to find anything.

example of the simple issue where closing tag of  is missing inside a template:
    template:
      `<div id="movie-filter">
        <h2>Filter results</h2>
        <div class="filter-group">
          <check-filter 
            v-for="ganre in ganres" 
            v-bind:title="ganre"
            v-on:check-filter="checkFilter" 
             <!-- forgot to close the tag with ">" --> 
            </check-filter>
        </div>
      </div>`

Thanks, any recomendations apreciated!

Comment: [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is one of the most widespread toolings for Vue. It highlights issues like the one you mention, and much more.